# How to put a black overlay overlay over the image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a slideshow made with js(which i did't attch), i want to make a black overlay over the image ive tried many ways but nothing is working for me .Here is my code can anyone help me please.The javascript is just to attach images to each span element.I want the black transparent overlay above the image and below the text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow with
        CSS3 - A Css-only fullscreen background image slideshow" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="css3, css-only, fullscreen, background,
        slideshow, images, content" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style4.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
        <li><span></span><div><h3>Picture perfect Designs</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>Perfect blend of Logic and creativity</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>Have an idea? contact us</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>Need a website for your buisness</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>qui·e·tude</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Codrops top bar -->
        <div class="codrops-top">

            <span class="right">

            </span>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->

        </div>
    </body>
</html>


<style>
.cb-slideshow, .cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}

.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: white;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

/* Animation for the title */

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

/* Show at least something when animations not supported */

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-size: 100px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*  .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }*/
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-size: 30px
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont want the overlay to be above all the content means 
you want an image some text content must be above it, and in between these two you want to have an overlay. If this is the case, then you have to **change the inside structure of a li.**

- First put the div with text content. (in your case you are using heading tag)
- Second put the new div with class overlay, and style background color
  for overlay class as rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
- Last, put the image tag.

Problem with this solution is that you have to create as number of overlay div as number of images.

**But if you want overlay over everything
then, you can add only new div just before the ul tag
with same css property.**

0.7 is alpha value, you can change it between 0-1 for different dark scales of overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add an `::after` pseudo element after your `li span` elements, like this:

```
.cb-slideshow li span:after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Working snippet (with kitten images):

```css
/* TAKIT: Added only this */
.cb-slideshow li span:after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.cb-slideshow:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}

.cb-slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li div {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/590/590);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/600);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/580/580);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/570/570);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/605/605);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/595/595);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}


/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


/* Animation for the title */

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


/* Show at least something when animations not supported */

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 100px
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /*  .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }*/
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 30px
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow with
        CSS3 - A Css-only fullscreen background image slideshow" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="css3, css-only, fullscreen, background,
        slideshow, images, content" />
  <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style4.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="page">
  <ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li><span></span>
      <div>
        <h3>Picture perfect Designs</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Perfect blend of Logic and creativity</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Have an idea? contact us</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 04</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Need a website for your buisness</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 05</span>
      <div>
        <h3>qui·e·tude</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 06</span>
      <div>
        <h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Codrops top bar -->
    <div class="codrops-top">

      <span class="right">

            </span>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <!--/ Codrops top bar -->

  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.